# Chrome's spellcheck using British spelling

Tags: google-chrome, spell-check

Chrome recently began correcting words with British spelling. I am not sure why this started happening, how can I revert back to American spelling?

In my language settings "English (United States)" appears at the top.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you check the box marked "`Use this language for spell checking`".

[image: Google Spellcheck]

If you don't see that box, or get a message saying that you can't use this language for spell checking you will need to perform a couple extra steps.

- Remove the language.
- Restart Chrome, you may need to close Chrome in the System Tray as well.
- Add the language again. This time the box should be available to tick.

Comment: I do not have the "Enable spell checking" check box in the bottom left, or the  "Use this language for spell checking" checkboxes on any my languages. Also I can not remove "English (United States)". I can remove my other languages though.

I am on OS X, so that might explain the differences.

Comment: @user71606 See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1335567/64305) for changing macOS spelling.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome 116 on Windows, the settings have changed. Search directly for "Spell Check"
[image]