# Set Google Chrome spelling to US English

Tags: google-chrome, spell-check, input-languages

My Google Chrome on an MBP highlights US English words as spelling errors.

For instance, "Monetization" and "Organize" Are marked as errors, while "Monetisation" and "Organise" are not marked as such:

Which appears in my editing pane as:

[image]

My language settings are:

[image]

**Any idea how to set Chrome to allow both US and UK spelling?**

Comment: What language is marked as _Google Chrome is displayed in this language_? What-if you try the following procedure?: 1. Add _English (United Kingdom)_ language; 2. Turn on both _English (United Kingdom)_ and _English (United States)_ spell checkers in _Spell Check_ section; 3. Turn on _Use a web service to help resolve spelling errors_ in _Privacy and security_ section.

Answer (score 17):

Go to macOS `System Preferences` > `Keyboard` > `Text` > `Spelling`, click `Set Up`, and in the popup menu, select `U.S. English` and drag it to the top of the list.

[image: Mac Spelling Language Setup Screenshot]

Also, see [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57883/how-can-i-change-the-language-for-automatic-spelling-correction) at apple.stackexchange.com.